# How to combine columns into one column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to sum some columns by id. But I'm retrieving 1 raw.

For Example

```
Id      | C1| C2| 
---------------------------------
1       | 2  | 1  | 
2       | 5  | 4  | 
3       | 3  | 1  | 
4       | 5  | 2  |
```

Result that I trying to get:

```
Id      |Total
---------------------------------
1       | 3  |
2       | 9  | 
3       | 4  | 
4       | 7  |
```

How can I combine columns into one?

Comment: Popeye already answered my question. I edited cause I can't post any question even six months past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need addition operation `+` as follows:

```
select id, c1+c2 as total 
  from your_table
```

Comment: it worked. I can't voting ı dont know why, thanks Popeye. I can vote in 8 minute

Comment: That's Okay. After few minutes, you will be able to accept the answer.

Comment: Barrels need to be scraped, I guess